# converting values with irregular intervals into minute values with excel

Tags: excel, time-series, intervals

I have a problem with an excel sheet which contains power readings as a time series. The problem is that it doesn't have regular intervals or times stamps, 
example:

```
15/3/2015 02:03 pm             3.4
15/3/2015 02:06 pm             5.0
15/3/2015 02:08 pm             6.0
15/3/2015 02:47 pm             4.0    
15/3/2015 03:17 pm             1.0
```

My task is to generate hourly energy data (`energy = power * time`), so my approach was to split the irregular sub-hourly data into minutes, then I integrate them easily afterward.

So I need them to be like this:

```
15/3/2015 02:03 pm        3.4
15/3/2015 02:04 pm        3.4
15/3/2015 02:05 pm        3.4
15/3/2015 02:06 pm        5.0
15/3/2015 02:07 pm        5.0
15/3/2015 02:08 pm        6.0
15/3/2015 02:09 pm        6.0
and so on...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done with VBA, and possibly with formulas. What have you tried so far to resolve this, and where have you gotten stuck? Not showing any research effort trying to solve this problem will most likely get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and you will be unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: I am allowed only to use simple excel formulas, I know how to do it easily with Python.
anyway, I feel like one function is capable to do it because it is basic, I just need the name of the function thats all :)

Comment: You could have a look at VLOOKUP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this easily with MAXIFS and SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I got Excel 2007, I do not have available the function [MAXIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883), and I'm forced to use an array formula, but I'm pretty sure this can be done easily with MAXIFS.

My data set is like this:

[image]

The formula I've used in E1 (and dragged down) is an array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(MAX(SI($A$1:$A$4<=E1;$A$1:$A$4));$A$1:$A$4;0))
```

> Because it's an array formula, it must be inserted pressing
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, instead of only
>   pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This is how it works:

1. `MAX(SI($A$1:$A$4<=E1;$A$1:$A$4))` will get the max date value that is <= than date in column E
2. We combine the value from step 1 with a `MATCH` to get the row number of that specific date
3. We combine value from step 2 with an `INDEX` to get the target value assigned to that specific date, and return it.

Anyways, as I said, I'm pretty sure you could get this easily with a MAXIFS to get the date, and then combine it with MATCH and INDEX.

Hope this helps.

**NOTE:** Because you are working with dates with minutes, and dates and times are numbers in Excel, actually you are working with decimal numbers (dates are integers and times are decimals). You must ensure that your values in both datasets are exactly the same, or it won't work!.

Let's see in 2 cells you got 2 values:

```
42078,5874998264
42078,5875000000
```

IF you apply a format like `dd/mm/yyyy h:mm AM/PM`, you will get this:

[image]

They look the same value **but that's not true**. Values of both cells are different, and that can make formulas show the wrong results. So you have to be 100% secure your dates in both datasets are exactly the same, or it won't work!

Comment: thank you very much, my problem solved easily by you.

Comment: @HamzaFares if the answer helped, please, mark it as correct so the question can be closed.